# Настройка  типов полей в .xml-манифесте для com_users в Joomla! 2.5

Tags: joomla

Передо мной стоит задача настройки полей редактирования юзером данных в своём аккаунте. Одно из полей (пол юзера) должно отображаться в виде радиокнопок. Как добиться этого? Когда я просто выставляю в манифесте (com_users/models/forms/profile.xml) для этого поля type="radio", оно пишет в коде буквально следующее:

```
 <fieldset id="jform_sex" class="radio"></fieldset>
```

...что совсем не то, конечно же... В БД данные размещаются в добавленном в основную таблицу (#__users) поле.
И вопрос №2 - как ему задать условие на отметку радиокнопки, соответствующей текущему значению? Т.е., корректно прописать то, что на PHP было бы примерно так:

```
<input type="radio"<? if ($option['sex']=='f') {?> checked<? }?>>
```

Буду признателен за ответ по существу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<field
    name="gender_users"
    type="radio"
    default="1">
    <option value="1">man</option>
    <option value="0">woman</option>
</field>
```

Оно??

Comment: Оно. Спасибо, друг! :)